# Using macro variables in SAS statements copied from %include

Tags: sas

I have a SAS frame program that I intend to use to call a separate SAS script a number of times.  Each time, the information the called SAS script will be different.

Can I set the values of macro variables in the frame program that can then be used by the called SAS script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If you set the macro variables prior to the `%include` statements, the macros called using `%include` will first look locally to resolve the macro variables and then look globally, which is where they will reside.  There are four ways to create a macro variable, but the one you'll probably want to use is `%let`.

If you're interested in being able to use macro variables outside of the macro where they were created, then you'll have to use `%global` to initiate the macro variables.

Comment: @Sam Curious what are the four ways to create a macro variable you are thinking of? 1. %let. 2. call symputx.  3. proc sql select into:.  4 ???    I suppose %GLOBAL and %LOCAL both create macro vars, and when you call a macro and pass parameters that creates macro vars, but wondering what your list would be.

Comment: @Quentin 1 through 3 are exactly right.  The fourth is, as you mentioned, when you call a macro and pass parameters.  `%GLOBAL` and `%LOCAL` may create macro variables but they do not populate them.